# Azure Devops can't run .NET Framework and dotnet core unit test in the same CI task

Tags: .net, unit-testing, build, azure-devops, vstest

I have a solution with .NET framework / .NET Core projects.

- library.csproj (.net standard)
- library.UnitTests.csproj (.net framework)
- WebApi.csproj (.net core)
- WebApi.UnitTests.csproj (.net core)

And I have a CI build via AzureDevops to export coverage on SonarQube.

So, after running, I got this error :

> Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X64
> Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
> WebApi.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 2.2 and Platform AnyCPU.

I tried to split pipeline into two steps then it works, but i lost the fist step code coverage.(Can't do much things related to sonarQube).

Any idea to run tests together in the same task? Or any another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem may be that the UnitTests.dll in your project is built for Framework 2.2 and Platform AnyCPU, but in the UnitTest task, Framework 4.0 and Platform x64 is used. You can add a `/Framework` parameter to solve this question.

```
/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0
```

Comment: I tried it and by doing that, only WebApi.UnitTests is tested. I got this message :
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0 and platform X64
Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
library.UnitTests.dll is built for Framework 4.6.1 and Platform AnyCPU